# How to determine after how many places of decimal the fraction ends.

Tags: linear-algebra

A question reads

> After how many places of decimals will the fraction $\frac{3}{2^{15}\times 5^{10}}$ end?

I gave the answer 10 as dividing by 10 we get a new decimal place and the max power of 10 will be 10. But the answer is given 15. So How to determine this? Please give proof, thank you.

Comment: I took the liberty of reformatting your question.  Can you please confirm that I interpreted your problem correctly?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang yes sir thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a rational number $\dfrac{p}{q}$ has a decimal expansion that terminates after $n$ decimal places then $\dfrac{10^np}{q}$ must be an integer. If $p$ and $q$ are co-prime then this means $q$ must be a factor of $10^n=2^n5^n$. So $q$ must be equal to $2^a5^b$ for some $a\ge0$ and $b\ge0$ and $n$ must be the greater of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: sir I dont get the last line- "n must be greater of a and b" . Can you give an example and explain. thank you. and so will the answer be 15 or 10?

Comment: In your original problem $a=15$ and $b=10$. But if you multiply by $10^{10}$ you still have a factor of $2^5$ in the denominator which is not cancelled, so you do not get an integer - there are still more decimal places.. To get an integer you must multiply by $10^{15}$. So the decimal expansion of the original fraction has 15 decimal places.

Comment: Sir 3/5^2 X 2^3 = 0.96. This ends after two places. I do not understand.

Comment: $\dfrac{3}{5^2}\times2^3=0.96$ but $\dfrac{3}{5^2 \times 2^3}=0.015$

Comment: oh sorry. I apologise.